# How do I mount a standalone Rack app into a Ruby On Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rack, mount

I have a running Rails app. Then, I have a little script that I would like to mount to the Rails app - here's the [script](https://github.com/andruby/as2/blob/master/examples/server.rb):

```
require 'as2'
require 'rack'

As2.configure do |conf|
  ...
end

handler = As2::Server.new do |filename, body|
  ...
end

MyBuilder = Rack::Builder.new do
  use Rack::CommonLogger
  map '/as2' do
    run handler
  end
end

puts "As2 version: #{As2::VERSION}"
```

I was researching how to mount the Rack app to the Rails app, and I should do something like this:

```
MyRailsApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MySinatraApp.new => '/api'
end
```

However, what I struggle with - what's the identificator (ID) of the Rack app? How do I set it and how do I connect these two apps and successfully mount them together?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** When I place the file (of which snippet I posted above) place to the `/lib` folder - the file's name **as2_server.rb** and to the routes I put the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  mount MyBuilder.new => '/as2'
end
```

I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant MyBuilder (NameError)
```

How (where) should I properly register the `MyBuilder` rack app?

Answer (score 3):

I think the only piece you're missing is requiring your Rack application.

So, to summarize, I would:

- put your script in lib/my_builder.rb
- create config/initializers/my_builder.rb
- add `require Rails.root.join('lib/my_builder')` to the new initializer
- mount with `mount MyBuilder, at: "/my_builder"` in config/routes.rb